# Are the Azure App Service Backups stored in both paired regions?

Tags: azure, service, backup

I have an Azure App Service (Premium) that is backing up my apps on the standard schedule.  All of that is working fine.  My question is, where are those backups located?  Are they just stored in the app's region or are they geo-replicated in the paired region as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where are those backups located? Are they just stored in the app's region or are they geo-replicated in the paired region as well?

Automatic backups are stored in the same region (datacenter) of App Service that is backed up as given in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup?tabs=portal#where-are-the-automatic-backups-stored).

[image]

Custom backups stored in Storage Account.

[image]

We can store the custom backups in the storage account located in any region but recommended to store close to the App service located.
[image]
By default, the storage account is in LRS if created from the App Service Portal Menu and can be changed accordingly:

[image]

Automatic backups are not stored in Storage Accounts but stored in the same datacenter where the App Service is hosted, and replication is based on the Zone-redundant type (enabled) of the App Service Plan.

If Custom backups are configured, then they will be stored in the Storage Accounts and replication is based on the Storage Account Replication Type.